# Excel: How do I sort by the two digits after a dash?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with about 85k rows and I'm trying to sort it by the alphanumeric digit that comes after `-`. For example:

```
 - AB1001-OE
 - AB1001-OE-1
 - AB1001-SS
 - AB1001-SS-1
 - AB1002-OE
 - AB1002-OE-2
 - AB1002-SS
 - AB1002-SS-2
 - AB1003-OE
 - AB1003-OE-1
 - AB1003-SS
 - AB1003-SS-1
 - AB1004-OE
 - 3
 - 34
 - 3471
 - 3473
 - 5406001
 - 5406002
 - 03471PA
 - 03473PA
 - 034PA
 - 375690-S
 - 380865-S
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to sort it by OE and SS and add a note for both, and it might be easier if I just type the note once and then copy the rest once it's sorted. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean sort by? do you want all OE's to be sorted? or do you just want to assigned a note to the OE's? if it's the latter you could probably just filer the column using a `text filter` then `contains` and type in OE

Comment: How does your question relate to coding? If it doesn't, it belongs on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following formula to get the `NOTE`in a helper column B.

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(MID(A9,SEARCH("-",A9)+1,2)="OE",MID(A9,SEARCH("-",A9)+1,2)="SS"),"YES","NO"),"")
```

Sort the helper column B by extending the range.

Hope this might help you.